# How can I get the properties of a function, which has an integral equal to zero?

Tags: distribution-theory

Let $\varrho \in L^\infty_{loc}$, where the set of discontinuity points is a Lebesgue null set, and $\varrho * \varphi$ is a polynomial with maximum degree of $m$ $\forall \varphi \in C_c^\infty$.
Now we know that
$$0=\frac{\mathrm{d}^{m+1}}{\mathrm{d} x^{m+1} } (\varrho * \varphi)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varrho(x-y) \frac{\mathrm{d}^{m+1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{m+1}}\varphi^{(m+1)}(y) dy.$$

I need this for an elaboration of a proof. There they state that with the help of Distribution theory I can follow that $\varrho$ is a polynomial.
Has someone maybe an idea how this works and can give me some input? Thank you very much

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to prove the identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ be a [mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Definition) and let $\varphi_n(x) = 2^{n} \varphi(2^n x)$ so that $\rho \ast \varphi_n \to \rho$ almost everywhere and as a distribution.

Since $\rho\ast \varphi_n$ is a polynomial of degree at most $m$, we can write
$$\rho \ast \varphi_n(x) = \sum_{k \le m} a_{k,n} x^k.$$

Now let $\psi \in C_c^\infty$ be a function such that $$\int \psi(x) x^k dx = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } k = 0 \\
0 \text{ if } 0 < k \le m. \end{cases}$$

Then $\langle \rho \ast \varphi_n , D^k \psi \rangle_{L^2} = (-1)^k a_{k,n}$ for each $k \le m$ so that $$(-1)^k a_{k,n} \to  \langle \rho, D^k\psi \rangle_{L^2} =: (-1)^k a_k$$ by the convergence as a distribution. Therefore, for almost all $x$, $$\rho(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k \le m} a_{k,n} x^k = \sum_{k \le m} a_k x^k.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have just one question: shouldn't $\varphi_n$ be defined with $\varphi_n(x)=2^{-n}\varphi(2^{-n}x)$?

Comment: No, $\varphi_n$ wants to be an approximation to the dirac delta in some sense so as $n \to \infty$, you want to have $\varphi_n(0)$ to go to $\infty$ and you want the support of $\varphi_n$ to shrink to $\{0\}$. This is achieved by the scaling I chose. Maybe you are confused because you often see written something more like $\varphi_\epsilon(x) = \epsilon^{-1} \varphi(\epsilon^{-1} x)$ which corresponds to my definition when $\epsilon = 2^{-n}$.

Comment: How can I see that the coefficients $a_{k, n}$ can be portrait like that?

Comment: @Lopsio are you asking why such a $\psi$ exists or why testing against derivatives of $\psi$ isolates the coefficients of the non-constant terms?

Comment: Why testing against the derivatives gives us the coefficients?

Comment: @Lopsio Use integration by parts to move the derivative onto the polynomial

Comment: Ok thank you! I just have one problem with that: for odd $k$, I get a negative sign from the second term from the integration by parts, which I seem to can't get rid of?

Comment: @Lopsio That's because I typed this in a rush and missed a $(-1)^k$. Thank you for pointing that out, it's now fixed.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your help!!!